# C++ Поля переменной длины в структурах

Tags: c++

Есть, например, такая структура:

```
struct FooStructure
{
    WORD Field1;
    WORD Field2;
    WORD Field3;
}
```

Все поля в ней имеют размер по 2 байта. Как поступить, если в процессе выполнения программы выяснилось, что для хранения значения в поле `Field2` не хватает места и нужно не 2, а 4 байта (`DWORD`). При этом использовать `DWORD` сразу с запасом на такие случаи не вариант, т.к. данные, которые потом разбиваются на поля структуры, идут в памяти последовательно.

---

Если говорить конкретно, задача разобрать таблицы метаданных управляемых модулей .NET. Поскольку в этих таблицах в большом количестве используются индексы объектов разного типа в других потоках метаданных, а эти индексы могут быть 2х или 4х байтными, использовать структуры для обработки метаданных проблематично.

Comment: если будете наливать молоко из бутыльки  в стакан , но не хватает место в стакане, что сделаете с оставшимся в бутыльке?...

Comment: Т.е. у вас вариантные данные (часть с одним размером полей, а часть с другим)? Видимо надо использовать 2 разных структуры и вместе с данными передавать признак, какой именно формат у них

Comment: @ARHovsepyan возьму стакан побольше и перелью в него.

Comment: @avp Использовать две структуры, в одной из которых `Field2` имеет тип `WORD`, а в другой, соответственно, `DWORD` - не очень то хорошая идея в моём случае. Ведь тогда мне придётся разделить весь блок кода, работающий с этими данными, на 2 повторяющиеся части: одна работает со структурой типа `FooStructure1`, другая выполняет тоже самое с `FooStructure2`. Да и к тому же, такая ситуация у меня на самом деле будет не только с `Field2`. Придётся создавать несколько структур, в которых будут разные сочетания типов нескольких полей.

Comment: Шаблоны? может это поможет)

Comment: @D.Stark, если вы опишете свою задачу, т.е. формат входных и выходных данных и процесс их обработки более подробно, то возможно получите более ценные советы

Comment: @avp Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @D.Stark, понятно. Типичная задача системного программирования (загрузчики, линкеры, отладчики ...). Думаю, правильным будет в точности описать данные набором структур, отражающим их расположение в источнике (файле или области памяти, занимаемой объектом, если он уже загружен). Затем вы можете перенести их (изменить их формат) в свои структуры, которые наиболее подходят для вашего кода.

Comment: @avp "Думаю, правильным будет в точности описать данные набором структур, отражающим их расположение в источнике" - это я и пытаюсь сделать, но некоторые поля имеют длину, указанную в других полях ранее. "Затем вы можете перенести их (изменить их формат) в свои структуры, которые наиболее подходят для вашего кода." - это по сути и не требуется.

Comment: @D.Stark, наверное поля имеют разную длину в разных таблицах. Каждую таблицу опишите своим набором структур. У вас исходники-то есть или реинжениринг по дизасму?

Comment: "наверное поля имеют разную длину в разных таблицах" - нет. Например, все строковые значения не хранятся непосредственно в таблицах. Вместо этого там хранятся смещения нужного значения в потоке `#Strings`. В зависимости от размера этого потока смещение может быть 2х или 4х байтным для всего модуля (указывается в заголовках потока таблиц метаданных).

Comment: И далее размер записи во всех таблицах уже будет зависеть от того каков размер поля смещения для данного модуля. Аналогична ситуация и с `#Blob`, `#GUID`, `#US`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут я бы посоветовал 2 варианта.

1: Шаблоны - тут я думаю все понятно, какой тип нужен - такой и пихайте

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct FooStructure
{
    T1 Field1;
    T2 Field2;
    T3 Field3;
}
```

2: Указатели - что вам угодно - аллоцируйте память под это туда и пихайте)))

```
struct FooStructure
{
    void* Field1;
    void* Field2;
    void* Field3;
}
```

3: все поля сделать union

```
Union t {
    Type1 t1,
    Type2 t2
 };
```

C++17:

4. Все поля сделать std::variant
5. Все поля сделать сделать std::any

Comment: Тогда просто шаблоны, Вы пишите код один раз, компилятор создаст столько имплементаций сколько вы закажете ) да объём объектных фалов увеличивается, на мы уже не в эпохе 32кб памяти )

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду создание шаблонной функции, которая у меня занимается обработкой этих данных? Действительно тогда не придётся дублировать код, но вызов такой функции будет выглядеть довольно таки витеевато.

Comment: Зачем? Структуры достаточно ) Добро пожаловать в мир мето-программирования)

Comment: Почему достаточно структуры? Если сделать шаблонной только структуру, то при создании экземпляра я не смогу присвоить одной и той же переменной экземпляры разных типов. Придётся для работы с каждым типом повторять один и тот же код.

Comment: Если же создать шаблон и функции и структуры, то тогда проблема решается, но вызов такой функции неудобен.

Comment: Тут решение за Вами, вы должны спроектировать модуль таким образом, чтобы его было легко поддерживать. Выбор той или иной стратегии работы с полями Вашей структуры все равно наложит некие ограничения или сопутствующие накладные расходы. Есть и третий вариант, все поля сделать union или std::variant - но нужно ли оно Вам?

Comment: На счёт сделать поля переменной длины объединениями не совсем ясно. Если я сделаю поля `Field2` и `Field3` объединениями `WORD` и `DWORD`, то при доступе к `Field3` как компьютер поймёт по какому смещению обратиться к этому полю (4 или 6 байт)?

Comment: Как к обычному union. Будите ручками указывать какой выбирать тип

Comment: Я не о том. Если структура выглядит так: `struct Foo { union { WORD wF1; DWORD dwF1; }; union { WORD wF2; DWORD dwF2; }; };`, по какому смещению будет осуществлён доступ к `dwF2`?

Comment: Если не указан alingof то по максимальному, куда тогда 2 Байта то прикапывать то надо ) потестируйте если сомневаетесь )

Comment: Я понимаю что вы хотите найти самый простой способ без проблем, с экономией места и тд, но думаю что такого нет. За двумя зайцами погонишься ...

Comment: Я предложил Вам 5 вариантов, если этот ответ Вас устроил нажмите голочку, если нет . Измерите описание вопроса. То о чем мы сейчас ведём беседу - уже тема под новый вопрос.

Comment: "Я понимаю что вы хотите найти самый простой способ без проблем, с экономией места и тд, но думаю что такого нет." - Пожалуй да, поэтому я буду разбирать данные без структур. Просто через приведение указателя к нужному мне значимому типу.